# How to determine local user account

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++, authentication, active-directory

I need to differentiate one of requirement functionality based on the local user account and domain user account in a domain joined system.

How can I detect currently logged on user is a local user account or domain user using C++?

Please suggest.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There are probably several ways, but an easy one is to use [`GetUserNameEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724435%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and request a format that isn't available in a non-domain context:

> If the user account is not in a domain, only `NameSamCompatible` is
>   supported.